# intellisense with jquery in visual studio 2010

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, intellisense

I put those two above. But I get no intellisense with jquery.

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I also want to achieve intellisense in a javascript file, is it possible?

---

**UPDATE:**

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $("").   //no click event handler comes up
});
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Simple google search came up with this:

[VS2010 Tips #7: How to make jQuery Intellisense work for external JavaScript file](http://blog.meidianto.com/2010/05/13/vs2010-tips-7-how-to-make-jquery-intellisense-work-for-external-javascript-file/)

Short answer:

```
/// <reference path="../../scripts/jquery-1.5.1-vsdoc.js"/>
```

Note that you can't use the `@` sign inside `js` file like in a Asp.net-MVC `View`

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7902213/asp-net-mvc-razor-symbol-in-js-file) to learn how you can overcome this.

Comment: when i choose an elemenet $("").   no click handler comes up ..why?

Comment: @BlackFire27. Did you add `/// <reference path="../../scripts/jquery-1.5.1-vsdoc.js"/>` to the file???

Comment: yeah. there is intellsense outside the jQuery(function($)..but not inside it.. it is very weird

Comment: @BlackFire27. You wrote the code wrong. It should be `jQuery($){$("").click(...)}`. Anyway I'm not sure you will get _intellsense_ inside that function because `$` in that function is a parameter!

Answer (score 7):

Right click the project >> Click on 'Add Library Package Reference' >> On the left frame select 'Online' >> On the right most corner frame, enter 'jquery' in the 'Search Online' textbox >> After results come, click and Install the 'jQuery.vsdoc' package.

Simple!

Comment: Hmmm, didn't even find the first option ("Add Library"). Are you sure this is for VS2010 (like the OP) or that there aren't any other requirements?

Comment: @CharlesRobertoCanato - Looks like you don't have Nuget installed on your VS2010 installation. please install it from below link and then try. Good Luck!

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/27077b70-9dad-4c64-adcf-c7cf6bc9970c

Comment: in fact I do, but the string is different than yours. Anyway I replied too early, didn't even notice you were talking about adding a package. Anyway I already tried that (manually, because I use an earlier version), still not working. Will investigate more in another time, thanks.