# jQuery ajax in js file

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am  using `ASP.Net-MVC3` and  I use this query in

**Layout.cshtml**:

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("EtiketGetir", "Etiket")',
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            data: data
        },
        success: function(msg) {},
        error: function(msg) {}
    });​
```

That works in `layout.cshtml`, but I copied that code and pasted to `test.js` file and it stopped working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved  my problem to use  this code

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/ControllerName/IndexName/',
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            data: data
        },
        success: function(msg) {},
        error: function(msg) {}
    });​
```

Comment: This works only in the local and not in server(Host application)

Answer (score 5):

That is because only razor handle the`@` sign, but it doesn't do it with `js` files.

```
url: '@Url.Action("EtiketGetir", "Etiket")',
```

For solutions read this post:
[**asp.net-mvc: razor '@' symbol in js file**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7902213/asp-net-mvc-razor-symbol-in-js-file)

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do in these cases is create an initialize function in my javascript file and pass it this data:

```
// test.js
(function(test, $, undefined) {
    test.initialize = function(options) {
        this.someUrl = options.someUrl;
    }

    test.someFunctionThatUsesUrl = function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.someUrl
        });
    }
})(window.test = window.test || {}, jQuery);
```

Then in the page that is using test.js I will call the initialize function:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    test.initialize({
        someUrl: '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")'
    });
```