# How to user @Html.Raw is not working in ui jquery autocomplete?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui-autocomplete, external-js

I used ui jquery auto-complete in my MVC3 web project and kept jquery in external js file and included it in the web page but it is not working.

I used following code in js file for ui jquery auto-complete :

```
$(function () {
    $("#ReportsTo_FullName").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            var linkPath = "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("AutocompleteSuggestions", "Employee", new { @term = "Term", @moduleName="ModuleName"}))";
            linkPath = linkPath.replace("Term", request.term);
            linkPath = linkPath.replace("ModuleName", "Employee");

            $.post(linkPath, function (data) {
                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                    return { label: item.FullName, value: item.Id }
                }
               ));
            })
            $.error(function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { alert(thrownError); })
        },
        minLength: 1,
        focus: function (event, ui) {
            $("#ReportsTo_FullName").val(ui.item.label);
            return false;
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            if (ui.item) {
                $("#ReportsTo_FullName").css('border', '');
                $("#ReportsTo_FullName").val(ui.item.label);
                $("#ReportsToId").val(ui.item.value);
                return false;
            }
        },
        change: function (event, ui) {
            if (ui.item == null) {
                $("#ReportsTo_FullName").css({ 'border': '1px solid #ff0000' });
                $("#ReportsToId").val(null);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

But it is failed to execute and its not showing autocomplete.

Whats wrong in above jquery ?

How to resolve this problem ?

Comment: To resolve this problem you should do some research first. You can check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7902213/944681), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4599169/944681) or [this](http://www.google.com) for starters..

Answer (score 2):

You can't use this:

```
@Html.Raw(Url.Action("AutocompleteSuggestions", "Employee", new { @term = "Term", @moduleName="ModuleName"}))
```

In js file, this is server code. Create hidden field on the page and only then you can get this data.