# How to do region collapse for JS in Visual Studio 2012/2013

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, region

Region code collapse for JS in Visual Studio 2012 and 2013 ?

```
#region AutoComplete JS
$("#<%=txtBirim.ClientID %>").autocomplete({
   source: function (request, response) {
     $.ajax({
       url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/Classlar/TextboxOtomatik.asmx/BirimGetir") %>',
       data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
       dataType: "json",
       type: "POST",
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       success: function (data) {
       response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
         return {
         label: item.split('-')[0],
         val: item.split('-')[1]
       }
      }))
     },
    Code....
#endregion
```

Is there anyway to do something like this ?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Install web essentials

Use the same name in end region

```
//#region AutoComplete JS
$("#<%=txtBirim.ClientID %>").autocomplete({
      source: function(request, response) {
          $.ajax({
                url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/Classlar/TextboxOtomatik.asmx/BirimGetir") %>',
                data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function(data) {
                  response($.map(data.d, function(item) {
                    return {
                      label: item.split('-')[0],
                      val: item.split('-')[1]
                    }
                  }))
                },
                Code....
//#endregion AutoComplete JS
```

Comment: you need to count with WebEssentials... http://vswebessentials.com/features/javascript

Comment: @QMaster install WebEssentials

Comment: although @umair solution working I will check to see WebEssentials was installed or not and If not I must decide about is it wise to install that just for using js region!

Comment: Installed WebEssentials but unfortunately not working in some section of JS code, e.g. $(document).on("click", ".....

Comment: The @umair solution is not persistent, unfortunately :(

Comment: I found all of the solutions have issues with Razor @ symbol in javascript if you have any. So I searched and this link must be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8794065/1830909

Answer (score 10):

It worked for me after installing the Visual Studio **Advanced Javascript Outlining** extension.

You can find the extension [here](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4be701d8-af03-40a4-8cdc-d2add5cde46c)

After installing the extension just restart your Visual Studio and you can use it like this

```
//#region MyRegion

Code Here

//#endregion
```

Comment: Solution posted is for VS version 2012/13 as asked by the OP.

Comment: The Advanced Javascript Outlining extension is not working with VS 2017 up to this moment. Is there some other way to get the region collapse for VS 2017?

Comment: For 2017- Download Extension from here https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.JavaScriptRegions

Comment: Validated working in .NET Core 6 projects, didnt need to add any extensions, just worked out the box in VS 2022

Answer (score 5):

1. select the javascript code you want to hide
   2.Press (

a.Ctrl+M

then

b.Ctrl+H 
)
then you can can name you region

Comment: more details on this page http://blog.degree.no/2013/05/define-a-region-in-javascript-files-visual-studio-2010-2012/

Comment: I upvoted this answer but I find after closing project outlines [ created with ctrl+M -> ctrl+H ] was removed :(

Answer (score 3):

if you use Web Essentials in Visual Studio than  you can write

```
//#region AutoComplete JS
youcode
//#endregion
```

see this [link](http://samirvaidya.blogspot.ru/2014/08/writing-javascript-with-regions-in.html)

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio:
Just select the code area you want to collapse then right click on the mouse, click on Outlining then click on Hide Selection.
You will get the collapse (+) sign on the left vertical bar.
The Shortcut Key is Ctrl+M then Ctrl+H after selection.