# 404.15 not found MVC4 RazorJS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, razorengine

I'm using `RazorJS` in my `MVC4` application for using the Razor syntax "@" in the Js file.

//Code:

```
@Html.RazorJSInclude("~/Scripts/Application/Transactions.js")
<button id="btnSearch" name="submit" type="button" onclick="Loadgrid();">Search</button>
```

The "Transaction.js" has "LoadGrid" mehtod inside. When i use my Transaction.js as the above code it throws me error as "No such method(Loadgrid) is found".

The rendered HTML in the browser shows like,

```
<SCRIPT src="/razorjs.axd?fn=/Scripts/Application/Transactions.js" type="text/javascript"></SCRIPT>
```

When i tried using like this,

```
<script src="~/Scripts/Application/Transactions.js"></script>
@Html.RazorJSInclude("~/Scripts/Application/Transactions.js")
```

The js file is accepted by the browser but the `ajax` call inside the js file is not getting called and throws me the following exception as an alert.

```
IIS 8.0 Detailed Error-404.15-Not Found
```

with some html content.

//Code in js file

```
function Loadgrid() {

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("LoadColumns", "Home")',
        data: { 'workflowId': '5' },
        datatype: 'json',
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        success: OnComplete,
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert(xhr.statusText);
                window.location.href = '@Url.Action("LogOut", "Account")';
        }
    });
}
```

//Controller:

```
    public ActionResult LoadColumns(string workflowId)
    {
      return Content("Success");
    }
```

The load columns method is not getting hit. Where i'm wrong?

FYI,

When using the url in the ajax call like `url: '/Home/LoadColumns'` the code woks very well but only in local machine and not in server(host in dev).

The RazorJS version is **0.4.3**

Source: [Razor inside Js file](http://john.katsiotis.com/blog/razorjs---write-razor-inside-your-javascript-files)

Comment: Although I have no answer I would like to thank you for pointing me to RazorJS, something I have needed quite often .

Comment: btw: did you install the application in subdirectory on the server?

Comment: @jao: No. Its just under the wwwroot.

Comment: @jao: Using colsole.log its showing  the value as @Url.Action("LoadColumns", "Home")

Comment: @InvernoMuto: No, i didn't use the ViewModel. Using completely in javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specify `datatype: 'json'` in your ajax call, but your controller action `return Content("Success");` where Content will be plain text and it is not allowed, change with something           `return Json(new { foo = "bar", baz = "Blech" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)`, then, you say the ajax call inside your script is not gettin called, then you say you retrieve an alert, this alert:

```
alert(xhr.statusText);
```

so your function is called as expected. Don't use alerts to debug, try:

```
console.log(error);
```

also the network tab of your preferred developer tools will do a better work then alerts.

[**Here you can find a simple working example**](https://bitbucket.org/InferOn/razorjs-test) to achieve your task:

**\Views\Home\Index.cshtml**

```
@Html.RazorJSInclude("~/Scripts/App/TestRazorJS.js")
<button id="btnSearch" name="submit" type="button" onclick="LoadFromRazor()">Search</button>
```

**\Scripts\App\TestRazorJS.js**

```
function LoadFromRazor() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("Test", "Home")',
    datatype: 'json',
    type: 'GET',
    cache: false,
    success: function () { console.log('done'); },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
      console.log(status);

    }
  });
}
```

**\Controllers\HomeController.cs**

```
public ActionResult Test()
    {
      return Json(new { foo = "bar", baz = "Blech" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

[image]

[image]

It work as expected.